# Stuck modal when position fixed bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, summernote

**I have summernote with position fixed bottom.**

`Link code: https://pastebin.com/raw/NDu97cRY`

When i run this code, my modal stuck. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please provide a minimal reproducible example. See here- [How to produce minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You could remove `<div class="col-12 fixed-bottom">` it can't be done other way if you are telling the code to always place it in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
If modal is in a div with position fixed bottom it will be stuck. So, saved outside the div.

```
$('.note-modal').appendTo("body");
```